# SSIS - Derived Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, derived-column

I have one small question, I am new so please help me.

In my project I have one text file which has `zip4` and `zip5` , I want to concatenate both the zip code but it has one problem, at some place zip4 is blank (not null) so when I used the derived column with

```
ISNULL(ZIP_4) ? ZIP_5 : (ZIP_5 + "-" + ZIP_4)
```

expression it will return the

> (zip5-)

where `zip4` is blank and I want only `zip5` without `-`.

So please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate in Sql Server or SSIS package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ISNULL([ZIP_4]) || LEN([ZIP_4]) == 0  ? [ZIP_5] : ([ZIP_5] + "-" + [ZIP_4])
```

or

```
ISNULL([ZIP_4]) || LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM([ZIP_4]))) == 0  ? [ZIP_5] : ([ZIP_5] + "-" + [ZIP_4])
```

Second one will trim `zip_4` both sides before checking its length.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI defined behaviour is that any operation involving `null` save an explicit test for nullity (`is [not] null`) yields null. Unfortunately, SQL Server's default behavior is non-standard. So...

You need to ensure that the following two settings are **on** for your stored procedure or turned on in your connection before you execute a standalone query:

- `set ansi_nulls on`
- `set concat_nulls on`

If you set these on in the body of the stored procedure, the settings only apply within that stored procedure; if you set them on for the connection (by executing the `set` statements), they are one for all queries executed on that connection (excepting that stored procedures have their own execution context).

It's a pity that you can't guarantee that missing data is always `null` rather than a nil string (`''`) — it makes the logic simpler.

Anyway, once you have proper `null behavior enabled, something like

```
-- if missing data is always NULL, do this
select zip9 = t1.zip5 + coalesce( '-'+t1.zip4 , '' )
from someTable t1
```

or

```
-- if missing data might be nil ('') or NULL, do this
select zip9 = t1.zip5
            + coalesce(
                '-'
                + case coalesce(t1.zip4,'') when '' then null else t1.zip4 end ,
                ''
                )
from someTable t1
```

should do the trick.

Otherwise, if you don't want to enable correct behavior, you can do something like this. This will work with standard NULL behavior as well. I just don't like it since it involves multiple tests. But [TMTOWTDI](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2008/01/tmtowtdi_the_right_way_to_do_i.html), as they say.

```
select zip9 = t1.zip5
            + case
                when t1.zip4 = ''    then ''
                when t1.zip4 is null then ''
                else '-' + t1.zip4
              end
from someTable t1
```

Comment: To address "pity that you can't guarantee that missing data is always null rather than a nil string" you can always use the [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to coerce the empty string to null value.

Comment: @billinkc: what do you think the standard function `coalesce()` does?

Comment: My apologies, brain went south as I was commenting. NULLIF will convert something to NULL if values match, so NULLIF(t1.zip4,'') would return NULL for nil strings as well as NULL values. This allows you to use your first code snippet `t1.zip5 + coalesce('-'+NULLIF(t1.zip4, ''), '')` instead of your more verbose case statement.